# change the priority of pythonpath

Tags: python, python-2.7, vtk, paraview, pygments

When I was loading certain modules [namely pygments.lexers Bash Lexer and pygments.formatters LatexFormatter] I was was getting an error that python couldn't find the modules. I then realised that this problem was being caused by my PYTHONPATH, which is set up for using [paraview](http://www.paraview.org/) with python. It brings its own version of pygments, which doesn't work with nbconvert from the jupyter notebook for some reason [Note it is not totally disfunctional, as PythonLexer, and a few others were called without a problem, it was only the ones that I've mentioned above that couldn't be found].

I have a similar problem with mayavi, which wouldn't work with paraview's version of vtk.

Both of these problems can be resolved simply enough by commenting out the python path in the bashrc, but obviously then paraview won't work.

Is there any way to, for example, reduce the priority of the PYTHONPATH so that the system codes in /etc... are called preferentially, but paraview can still find the ones that it needs in the PYTHONPATH?

I am using python 2.76 on linux mint 17.3, paraview is version 4.4.0, installed from source code as per [here](http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Installation/Linux/OpenFOAM-3.0.x/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can `import sys` and manipulate `sys.path` as an ordinary list at runtime. You can rearrange what's there, or just insert at the beginning (`sys.path.insert(0, 'path')`). Do this before your `import` statement. If this will cause problems elsewhere, put it back after your `import` statement.

Note, this is fairly hacky. But it sounds like you might have a case for it, although I have not looked at these specific tools together.

Edit: this is more relevant if you want to control the python path at the level of *individual imports* within the course of one execution of python. If you want to control the path at the level of one full execution of Python, you can also set the python path on the command line for just that execution like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/replacement/path/here python your_script.py
```

This is more verbose (unless you wrap it in a shell script or alias) than just calling python, but it lets you control the path one script at a time, wheres putting it into `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` or similar changes it for your whole shell session.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to be working, it just adds 'path' to the start of sys.path, when I import the same functions - pygments.lexers, for example -  it is still calling the ones from the python path

Comment: 'Path' represents the filesystem path you want to insert.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. That's working fine for calling functions in a code, however it still won't work for calling functions from the command line. I tried calling it inserting it in my pythonrc, but still I get the same errors calling apps from the command line

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I thought you needed to be able to use both pythonpaths within the same execution to make two different things work.

Comment: If you just need to control it per command line execution then you should probably use the `PYTHONPATH` env var.

Comment: You mean just append the relevant system path directories to the beginning of the pythonpath? I did think of this, my concern is that then the pythonpath directories will be doubling up on the system paths, which as you said is kind of 'hacky', was hoping for a cleaner solution, but that should work

Comment: See my edit for if you want to set the path in the shell but not 'globally'

Answer (score 1):

Ordering the entries in PYTHONPATH is partly right, but the system paths don't seem to get included *until you run python*, and then they get put at the end. So to put a system path in front, explicitly add it:

```
export PYTHONPATH="[path/to/system/files]:$PYTHONPATH"
```

It is kind of a hack, because the system path you add will be duplicated in sys.path. But it works.

Answer (score -1):

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<your_path>` will give priority to system paths and only if something is not there will look on your path.

`export PYTHONPATH=<your_path>:$PYTHONPATH` will search `<your_path>` firstly and then $PYTHONPATH for what it does not find.

If something exists in both but you want to use one version of it for one program and the other for another then you might want to look on different bashrc profiles.

Comment: I tried implementing this, but it doesn't seem to be working. Python is still reading $PYTHONPATH first, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you launching the programs from the terminal? Cause if you don't and you launch them from their shortcut launchers then `PYTHONPATH` is not set. Also what is the output (run in a terminal) of `echo $PYTHONPATH$?

Comment: launching from the terminal, echo $PYTHONPATH returns :/home/sean/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-3.0.x/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-4.4.0/lib/paraview-4.4/site-packages:/home/sean/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-3.0.x/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-4.4.0/lib/paraview-4.4/site-packages/vtk

Comment: And that is the priority of the paths. But to be taken into account the programs need to be launched from the terminal, are you doing so?

Comment: Yes, the programs are being launched from the terminal, the problem is that I want to change the order so that the system path takes priority before the openFOAM directories

Comment: This is already addressed in my answer `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<your_path>`, this will give priority to the already existing PYTHONPATH. Priority is left to right so it is up to you how you set them. If you want to change the priority upon executing a specific program write a small script as the other answer describes and call the programs via these scripts.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work on my system, it just prints <your_path> (or whatever else is in my $PYTHONPATH)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained myself clearly. I'm not looking to include the path at the end of the pythonpath, I'm trying to make the pythonpath read after the rest of the system path. Check out the answer from Jason S